# Eav attribute type int which input to use

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, attributes

I am currently creating some product attributes and some of them should be of type integer but Magento doesn't offer any input type for integer values.

If I use `'input' => 'text'` it seems that Magento parses it into int and if I enter a correct int value it's stored correctly. On the other hand, if I enter a string value like "abc" it's just stored as 0.
I am not sure whether it's a good practice to just use `'input' => 'text'` or if it has many risks and there's a better way to handle those cases. What could be the risks of using text as an input method?

I don't really want to use varchar for them because they are clearly numbers and parsing them to int with a backend_model is not a good approach either in my opinion. And using `'input' => 'price'` too, due to it's a decimal indication.

**Update**
Based on the comment of Alex is it okay to use combinations of `'input'` and `'type'` that are not used when you create a attribute from backend or what could be risks of that??

Comment: I think there are certain combinations of input and backend/frontend modles which are supported by the Magento backend and other's not. The question for me is, whether it is fine to use the combinations which are not supported by the backend attribute creation in update scripts or not.

Comment: The problem here is when you choose one of the input types from backend you cannot have integer values. Integers are used for selects and boolean inputs. For a input field where you can freely insert values you have to use text fields or price and neither of them are good choices in my opinion